# Is it possible to omit header rows when exporting a SageMaker DataWrangler flow to s3 (via a Jupyer Notebook)?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio, aws-data-wrangler

I am exporting a DataWrangler flow to s3 via a Jupyter Notebook using SageMaker Studio. Each of the resulting CSV files (each containing a part of the transformed dataset) include a header row with the column names. However when using a CSV file as training input for a Sagemaker estimator, header rows are not accepted. Is there an option in DataWrangler to export to s3 without header rows?

Comment: I don't believe data wrangler flow has the ability to export without headers out of the box. You can process the output dataset to remove the header though.